# C# web application cannot see second level C dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a strange problem calling C dlls from C# windows/web applications.

**Scenario is:**
We have a C# web application that uses a C# dll (csharp1.dll).
This csharp1.dll in return calls some functions from a C dll (c1.dll).
And c1.dll in return calls another C dll (c2.dll) for some lower functions.

**Details:**
In the implementation of csharp1.dll, there are pinvoke lines such as:

```
[DllImport("c1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern unsafe internal void *openhw(int id);
```

However, there is no direct reference to c2.dll, c2.dll is loaded by `LoadLibrary("c2.dll")` in c1.dll.

**Problem:**
When csharp1.dll is added to a C# windows console application, it works fine and all functions of c1.dll and c2.dll can be used.
When csharp2.dll is added to a C# web application, c1.dll is loaded, however c2.dll cannot be loaded.

This problem only happens when used within a C# web application, which is being run from the webserver IIS. Thus, I have tried putting c2.dll even into the windows directory, thinking that calling process (IIS) cannot see c2.dll, no luck. And I cannot see any problem with the `LoadLibrary("c2.dll")` call.

What may cause such a problem? And how may I solve this without altering implementations of c1.dll and c2.dll?

**update:** I have tried adjusting the trust level and disabling the ShadowCopying, neither helped.

Comment: where is the c dll located? what is the trust level of your application?

Comment: C dlls are located in the windows folder, just to make sure any application can load it. about the trust level, noting is altered for the project specifically, so it must be on the default level.

Comment: It'd help if you posted any error code / message.

Comment: The application itself does not give any error because it is handled in c1.dll where LoadLibrary("c2.dll") returns null. This is the problem.

Comment: @Alparslan, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) right after `LoadLibrary("c2.dll")` returned NULL and you'll know more about why it happened.